# Objective-C: init vs initialize

Tags: objective-c, initialization, init, initializer

In Objective-C, what is the difference between the `init` method (i.e. the designated initializer for a class) and the `initialize` method? What initialization code should be put in each?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`-init` is an instance method, used to initialize a particular object. `+initialize` is a class method, run before any instances of the class are created and before other class methods are run. `+initialize` isn't something you use most of the time, but it's handy for setting up any static variables that the class as a whole might use, or for ensuring that certain conditions are met before any instances are created.

The code that belongs in an `-init` method is described thoroughly in the [Implementing an Initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4) section of [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2). There's also some discussion of initializing classes (i.e. `+initialize`) and why you might need to do that in the same document, in the [Class Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-TPXREF115) section. The code that goes into `+initialize` will generally be strongly tied to the special functionality of the class that requires you to initialize it in the first place. One important thing to keep in mind in `+initialize` (and in any class method) is that `self` in a class method refers to the class itself, not an instance of the class.

Comment: "run before any instances of the class are created" not really: ***sent*** before that class *receives it's first message* (excluding the `+initialize` method). You can, in fact create an instance of a class without sending that class a message (with the `IMP` of it's create-instance method (usually `+allocWithZone:` but this can vary)).

Comment: @WTP, fair point, but if you're operating in that space you're probably pretty clear on the distinction between +initialize and -init already.

Comment: I usually see `if (self == [NameOfClass class])` inside `+initialize` method, why do we need to check that? I know it's something to do with `+initialize` method being called on parent class twice, but it's not clear for me. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @makaed Your question is answered nicely in the [docs](http://bit.ly/1eSNpGI) -- here's the relevant line: *The superclass implementation may be called multiple times if subclasses do not implement initialize—the runtime will call the inherited implementation...* So, even though `+initialize` is called only once per class, a single implementation might be called several times -- once for the class in which it's  and once for each subclass that doesn't provide it's own `+initialize` method.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Now that makes sense. I also created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200377/implementation-of-init-vs-initialize) and had some good answers.

Answer (score 19):

To draw a parallel for Java developers, init is like a constructor, while initialize is like a static block on a class.