# Extend NSURLCache cannot use parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlcache

I have a class URLCache extends NSURLCache

in URLCache.m

```
+ (void)initialize {

    NSString *_cacheSubFolder = nil;
    NSUInteger _cleanCacheFilesInterval;
    if (_pageType == FirstPage) {
        _cleanCacheFilesInterval = FirstPageCleanCacheFilesInterval;
        _cacheSubFolder = @"/WebCatchedFiles/FirstPage/";
    }else if (_pageType == SecondPage){
        _cleanCacheFilesInterval = SecondPageCleanCacheFilesInterval;
        _cacheSubFolder = @"/WebCatchedFiles/SecondPage/";
    }else if (_pageType == ThirdPage){
        _cleanCacheFilesInterval = ThirdPageCleanCacheFilesInterval;
        _cacheSubFolder = @"/WebCatchedFiles/ThirdPage/";
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    cacheDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:_cacheSubFolder];
//    cacheDirectory = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    removeFilesInCacheInDueTime(cacheDirectory, _cleanCacheFilesInterval);
    createDirectry(cacheDirectory);
    supportSchemes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"http", @"https", @"ftp", nil];
}
```

If A.m calls URLCache.m then A needs to send param _pageType into URLCache, I don't know how to send _pageType in. I tried

```
-(void)setPageType:(NSUInteger)pageType{
    _pageType = pageType;
}
```

but everytime in A.m

```
URLCache *sharedCache = (URLCache *)[NSURLCache sharedURLCache];
    [sharedCache setPageType:self.naviType];
```

got

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLCache setPageType:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xabd1470'

why cannot send param to NSURLCache?

How to send _pageType in?

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]
```

returns the shared URL cache instance. If you have not set a custom instance with `setSharedURLCache:`, this is an `NSURLCache` object.

The type cast `(URLCache *)` does not change the object and does not "convert" it to a `URLCache` object. You can verify that with

```
NSLog(@"class = %@", [sharedCache class]);
```

That is the reason why `[sharedCache setPageType:...]` throws an exception.

Note also that `initialize` is a *special class method* that is run once before any instances of that class are created (good explanation and links here: [Objective-C: init vs initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191480/objective-c-init-vs-initialize)). It does therefore not make sense to check for `_pageType` in `initialize`.

So you have to create a instance of your `URLCache` class first, which you then can set as shared instance with

```
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:...]
```